# How to define an async static protected class memeber in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, ecmascript-6, access-modifiers

I'm trying to declare an async static **protected** class method in Javascript?

```
module.exports = class MyClass {

    protected static async foo(bar) {  }
    static protected async foo(bar) {  }
    static async protected foo(bar) {  }
}
```

None of the above declarations or Googling work! How are access modifiers handled here? Please provide both ES6 and regualar js declarations.

Comment: The `protected` keyword doesn't exist in JavaScript, only in TypeScript.

Comment: *"How are access modifiers handled here? "*  They don't exist. Every property is public. Private class field are official coming next year (https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md).